# BigQuery - Group by and use an array field as a filter

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery

Hello guys I saw that there are some questions about group by with arrays but none of them (as far as I searched) did not use an array field as a filter for a result! In my case I have an address array and would like to group by the record update date and look for only the home address as per query below.

```
WITH last_update AS (SELECT
        owner_id,
        created_at,
        MAX(updated_at) as updated_at
      FROM
        dataset.profile
      GROUP BY
        owner_id, created_at )
SELECT
    profile.name  ,
    profile.emails  ,
    profile.phones  ,
        profile_addresses.city_name  ,
    profile_addresses.state_code,
    FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m', last_update.created_at ) AS month
FROM dataset.profile AS profile
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(profile.addresses) as profile_addresses
INNER JOIN last_update ON profile.owner_id = last_update.owner_id and profile.updated_at = last_update.updated_at and profile.created_at = last_update.created_at

WHERE (profile.status = 'ACTIVE')
AND (profile_addresses.type = 'HOME')
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6
ORDER BY 6 DESC
```

> Failed to retrieve data - Grouping by expressions of type ARRAY is not
>   allowed at [22:12]

Comment: hard to reverse engineer your use-case from non-working query - instead can you present some simplified example of input data and expected result along with logic to produce it. I think this will highly increase chances for the question to be answered with something meaningful

Comment: If you remove `emails` and `phones` (and change group/order by statements) does your query work?  I'm guessing those are arrays similar to `addresses`.

Comment: It might also be easier/clearer to get the most recent profile via a window function and then select the data you need from each user's most recent profile.

Comment: Any why do you need to group by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `profile.emails` and `profile.phones` fields triggering the error, enclosing them as below will fix the error:

```sql
    ARRAY_TO_STRING(profile.emails, " ")  ,
    ARRAY_TO_STRING(profile.phones, " ")  ,
```

Comment: You don't really need GROUP BY. If only to dedup multiple address, you can use SELECT DISTINCT. They are semantically equivalent in your case, but a little more clear.

Comment: Even without the group by it was not running ... in fact there was an array field in the table that was unknown and the solution mentioned helped solve the problem.